# ReactJS: How can I play an html5 video with an onClick event correctly with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

In my react component I have a video tag like so:

```
  <video>
    <source src="https://fake.com/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
```

And I have a button a bit further down that I would like to use to activate the video:

```
<button onClick={playVideoFunc?}/>
```

I assume I will be using some sort of on click event to trigger the video play and I know I can use the following javascript code to do it:

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.play();
```

But sense this is my first time using react I was wondering if there was a  more "reacty" way of doing this? Additionally if I do have to use pure javascript like above is it appropriate to put that code inside the react component itself? For reference my component looks like this (minus some details):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Footer from './footerComponent'
import Navbar from './navbarComponent';


class Home extends React.Component{
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="wrapper home-page">
        <div className="jumbotron-video-wrapper">
          <video>
            <source src="https://fake.com/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
        <Navbar type={"transparent"}/>
        <div className="jumbotron margin-bottom-20" style={heroStyle}>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                <h1>WORDS WORDS WORDS</h1>
                <img onClick={playvideo??} width="130" src={playImage}/>
                <p className="thin">Watch our video</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute) to your video element and call play() using **this.refs.video.play()**.

```
class Home extends React.Component{
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="wrapper home-page">
        <div className="jumbotron-video-wrapper">
          <video ref="video">
            <source src="https://fake.com/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
        <Navbar type={"transparent"}/>
        <div className="jumbotron margin-bottom-20" style={heroStyle}>
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                <h1>WORDS WORDS WORDS</h1>
                <img onClick={() => {this.refs.video.play()}} width="130" src={playImage}/>
                <p className="thin">Watch our video</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: This works, but isn't to different from the other way I could do it. But i guess this is the way react is meant to be used?

Comment: Yeah, at least for small things like triggering an event. Otherwise you should create a component.

Answer (score 2):

you could also do onClick={e => e.target.play()} on the video element.
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useRef hook to make a reference to the video. Then inside the onClick function you can play the video. You can do something like this.

The "Video" in the image is a styled-component of a video tag. FYI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOhKg.png)